# Lines through a plane in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking to reproduce the following figure in tikz. Could anyone help?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \draw (-4,0,4) node[left] {$d_\infty-d_\infty'$} -- (4.5,0,4) coordinate (P);
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
  \draw (-4,-2) rectangle (4,2);
  \draw (-3.9,-1) -- (3.9,-1) node[right] {$d$}
  (-3.9,1) -- (3.9,1) node[right] {$d'$};
  \foreach \X in {-3.8,-3.5,...,3.8}
   {\draw[dashed] (\X,1) -- (P) (\X,-1) -- (P);}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note to myself: it seems that loading the `3d` library is no longer necessary, it gets auto-loaded with `tikz-3dplot` along with `calc` and `arrows`.)